# Hibernate - Criteria Queries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my current project I've faced a problem of getting entities with hibernate criteria query. I have Employees and Tasks entities.

Tasks entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="task")
public class Tasks implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7988799579036225137L;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="employee_id")
private Employees employees;

public Employees getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

****relevant getters & setters******
```

Employee entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employees implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -7988799579036225137L;

@Id
@Column(name="employee_id")
private String empId;

****relevant getters & setters******
```

I'm trying to set the empId from a form and display the relevant tasks for the relevant employee. I have to give this restriction to the criteria API. My current code is as below. I'm wondering how can i do it. please give me a help. Thanks in advance.

ViewAssignedTasksDaoImpl.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ViewAssignedTasksDaoImpl implements ViewAssignedTasksDao {

@Autowired
private HibernateUtilImpl hibernateutilimpl;

@Resource(name = "sessionFactory")
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public List<Tasks> viewassignedTasks(Tasks tasks) {


    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    Employees employees = tasks.getEmployees();

    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Tasks.class);
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("empId", tasks.employees.getEmpId()));
    List<Tasks> tasksList = cr.list();

 return tasksList;

}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: all the rows are returning without a restriction.

Comment: just check whether your tasks.empoyees.getEmpId() return correct value..better way to log and check

Comment: Any reason why the line " cr.add(Restrictions.eq("empId", tasks.employees.getEmpId()));" is not " cr.add(Restrictions.eq("empId", employees.getEmpId()));"? Why are you trying to access tasks private fields without a getter?

Comment: yes it should be changed as you said.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this  will  help you  ..

```
ArrayList<Tasks> TasksListByEmpId = (ArrayList<Tasks>) this
                        .getSession()
                        .createCriteria(Tasks.class,"task")
                        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
      .add(Projections.property("task.yourproprty_name"), "yourproprty_name")
       .add(Projections.property("task.yourproprty_name"), "yourproprty_name")
        .add(Projections.property("task.yourproprty_name"), "yourproprty_name")
      .add(Projections.property("task.yourproprty_name"), "yourproprty_name"))
                        .add("empId", tasks.employees.getEmpId()))
                        .add(Restrictions.in("task.taskStatus", statusList))
                        .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Tasks.class))
                        .list();
```